# Cumulative conditional product with reset

Tags: r, dataframe, finance, xts, cumulative-sum

I have a large xts object. However the example is in a data.frame two column subset of the data. I would like to calculate (in a new column) the cumulative product of the first column `df$rt` whenever the second column `df$dd` is less than 0. Whenever `df$dd` is 0 I want to reset the cumulating to 0 again. So for the next instance that `df$dd` is less than 0 the cumulative product starts again for `df$rt`.

The following example dataframe adds the desired outcome as column three `df$crt`, for reference. Note that some rounding has been applied.

```
    df <- data.frame(
  rt = c(0, 0.0171, 0.0796, 0.003, 0.0754, -0.0314, 0.0275, -0.0323, 0.0364, 0.0473, -0.0021),
  dd = c(0, -0.0657, -0.0013, 0, -0.018, -0.0012, 0, 0, 0, -0.0016, -0.0856),
  crt = c(0, 0.171, 0.0981, 0, 0.0754, 0.0415, 0, 0, 0, 0.473, 0.045)
)
```

I have tried various combinations of `with`, `ifelse` and `cumprod` like:

```
df$crt <- with(df, ifelse(df$dd<0, cumprod(1+df$rt)-1, 0))
```

However this does not reset the cumulative product after a 0 in `df$dd`, it only writes a 0 and continues the previous cumulation of `df$rt` when `df$dd` is below zero again.

I think I am missing a counter of some sort to initiate the reset. Note that the dataframe I'm working with to implement this is large.

Comment: Please show expected ouptut.  Do you need `df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(dd < 0)) %>% mutate(crt = cumprod(1 + rt)-1)`

Comment: The expected outcome is df$crt. That dplyr solution does not give the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes it works in dplyr. I did not mention that I have an xts object. Is there a way to do it in base r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a grouping column by taking the cumulative sum of logical vector (`dd == 0`) so that it increments by 1 at positions where dd is 0, then use `replace` with the condition to do the cumulative product  in 'rt' only in places where 'dd' is not equal to 0

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(dd ==  0)) %>% 
    mutate(crt1 = replace(dd, dd != 0, (cumprod(1 + rt[dd!=0]) - 1))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
        rt      dd    crt   crt1
     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  0       0      0      0     
 2  0.0171 -0.0657 0.171  0.0171
 3  0.0796 -0.0013 0.0981 0.0981
 4  0.003   0      0      0     
 5  0.0754 -0.018  0.0754 0.0754
 6 -0.0314 -0.0012 0.0415 0.0416
 7  0.0275  0      0      0     
 8 -0.0323  0      0      0     
 9  0.0364  0      0      0     
10  0.0473 -0.0016 0.473  0.0473
11 -0.0021 -0.0856 0.045  0.0451
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(df, ave(rt * (dd != 0), cumsum(dd == 0), FUN = function(x)
        replace(x, x != 0, (cumprod(1 + x[x != 0]) - 1))))
```

-ouptut

```
 [1] 0.00000000 0.01710000 0.09806116 0.00000000 0.07540000 0.04163244 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.04730000 0.04510067
```

Comment: This works great! Is there also a non dplyr method that could work with an xts object? In base r?

Comment: Thank you Akrun!